# In a weighted tree, must the vertex with the least eccentricity always be the root of the tree?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, graph, tree

Let G be a graph and v be a vertex of G. The eccentricity of the vertex v is the maximum distance from v to any vertex. That is, e(v)=max{d(v,w):w in V(G)}.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, because any node of a tree can be chosen to represent its root.

Therefore it is not necessary that one of the nodes with least eccentricity was also selected as root.